# Instead of deleting an array I want it to send the array to another UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create a function that allows a user to select several videos and then select a button and it will send the selected videos to another array. I already have a similar function that handles deletions. I was really just trying to repurpose the code I already have for the deletion but everything I have tried has failed. I am a Swift newb but is there a way to do this or a better approach I should take?

```
var videos = [PHAsset]()
var dictionarySelectedIndexPath: [IndexPath: Bool] = [:]

@objc func didDeleteButtonClicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var deleteNeededIndexPaths: [IndexPath] = []
    for (key, value) in dictionarySelectedIndexPath {
        if value {
            deleteNeededIndexPaths.append(key)
        }
    }
    for i in deleteNeededIndexPaths.sorted(by: { $0.item > $1.item }) {
        videos.remove(at: i.item)
    }
    collectionView.deleteItems(at: deleteNeededIndexPaths)
    dictionarySelectedIndexPath.removeAll()
}

func getVideos() {
    let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.video, options: nil)
    assets.enumerateObjects({ (object, count, stop) in
        self.videos.append(object)
    })
    
    self.videos.reverse()
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "ItemCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
    collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "videoEditorSegueIdentifier" {
        let otherVc = segue.destination as! VideoEditorVC
        otherVc.videos = videos
    }
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ItemCollectionViewCell            
        let asset = videos[indexPath.row]
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()

        if cell.tag != 0 {manager.cancelImageRequest(PHImageRequestID(cell.tag))}
        
        cell.tag = Int(manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 120.0, height: 120.0), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil) { (result, _) in cell.imageView?.image = result
        })
        
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the issue you're having is because you're storing `indexPath` in a dictionary to remember what was selected and you're having difficulty translating that into actual data you're holding.

This would be far easier if you cut out the middle man and simply populated the array with actual selected objects in your `didSelectItemAt` method.

Something in the lines of:

```
var selectedVideos = [PHAsset]()

func videoFor(indexPath: IndexPath) -> PHAsset {
    // return the video more or less the same as you do it in cellForItemAt:
}

func indexFor(video: PHAsset) -> Int? {
    return selectedVideos.firstIndex(of: video)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let video = videoFor(indexPath: IndexPath)
    if selectedVideos.contains(video) {
        selectedVideos.remove(at: index)
    } else {
        selectedVideos.append(video)
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the code but at the let video = videoFor line I am getting an error that says, "Cannot convert value of type 'IndexPath.type' to expected argument type 'UICollectionView'" and at the selectedVideos.remove line I am getting an error that says, "Cannot convert value of type(Any) -> Int to expected argument type 'Int'. I also updated my OP with the cellForItemAt so you can see what I am doing there. I suspect that is the source of the issue but I can tell.

Comment: The code I wrote above is more of a guideline than actual code you can use. Your errors are verbose enough and I suggest taking a bit of time to solve them yourself :)